# Can the accountIdentifiers field be filled for existing subscriptions?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

the accountID and profileID can be sent while starting the subscription with the following field, and then these values can be read when the products purchased by the user are taken from the store.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#getAccountIdentifiers()

My question is: If this field is null for existing subscriptions that have been initiated and renewed before, can this field be filled without affecting the subscription in any way?